# App_theme not adding styles to web page

Tags: asp.net, app-themes

I have a web site project that uses an App_theme folder for styles. When I run the site the styles are not applied to the site. What is going on?

It works on other developers computers, but they are using a local IIS 7 server whereas I am using the built in Visual Studio IIS. Note - the site is setup using a web site project (not application).

Comment: have you added the style sheet reference to page?

Comment: The style is being applied like this <pages theme="SomeTheme">

Comment: Are you using WindowsAuthentification and a login?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is in incorrect folder name - `~/App_Themes` instead of yours `App_theme`?

Right click on your website -> Add ASP.NET Folder -> App_Themes; this will add theme folder automatically, and then you will be able to add themes there.

Answer (score 1):

To apply a theme to a WebSite, it is necessary to set the  element to the name of the theme, either a global theme or a page theme, as shown in the following example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages theme="ThemeName" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk.aspx)

Comment: I have that in there, but the style isn't getting applied for some weird reason

Comment: You can try to create a sample page and handle the PreInit event to ensure whether the theme, specified within the <pages theme /> key is applied correctly by using the page’s Theme property.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the top of the page includes the "theme" attribute, here's an example of the default page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" Title="Reset Sessions" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WorkbenchWeb.resetsession" Theme="Theme" StyleSheetTheme="Theme" %>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did too!

Answer (score 0):

Theme is there, i check Init event and theme is in web.config for all pages, however for some reason css under App_Themes are not added to one of the pages. However, for other pages it's ok - added automatically.